# Unable to create partitions on vmdk device in Docker

Tags: docker, lvm, vmdk, parted

Is it possible to create a `vmdk` image using Docker?

My actions for this:

I activate the `nbd` module, launch a container with privileges.

```bash
# qemu-img create -f vmdk image.vmdk 10G
Formatting 'image.vmdk', fmt=vmdk size=10737418240 compat6=off hwversion=undefined
# qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.vmdk
# parted /dev/nbd0 mklabel gpt
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/nbd0 mkpart BIOS_Boot_Partition 2048s 4095s
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/nbd0 set 1 bios_grub on
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/nbd0 mkpart LVM 4096s 100%
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/nbd0 set 2 lvm on
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# pvcreate /dev/nbd0p2
  No device found for /dev/nbd0p2.
```

That is, after creating partitions on `vmdk`, `nbd0p*` links are not created on them.
The same algorithm works outside of docker. Maybe you need to give some permissions to create links?

Comment: Usually a Docker container doesn't have access to host hardware devices and doesn't have permission for some operations like filesystem mounts.  I'd do this sort of work outside a container (maybe from a dedicated external boot device).